# Is backbiting (doing चुगली ) about wrong doings of someone sin?

Tags: sin

Is backbiting (doing चुगली) about wrong doings of someone sin ? Is informing about someone's sin to some other person sin ?

Suppose I see someone doing something wrong and I inform about his wrongdoing to some other person , then am I committing sin ?
Should we keep out of business of other people ? Should we let the destiny do its job ?

Comment: Good question, thx for asking this. Reply below by Pradip is good 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally backbiting is not recommended by Hindu scripture.

> Even after knowing the defects of others, one should not proclaim them
> to others – this is another passage in the Sruti.

**Linga Purana I.8.14**

However, if you see someone doing something wrong like stealing or something seriously wrong then you should inform the appropriate authorities.

Comment: Thx for posting this reply. There are a couple people who messed with me and made my life horrible earlier (female relatives in family, terrible people.) It’s not going on anymore, I finally got away from them. But I can’t seem to stop whining & complaining, I’m going off about it every chance I get to people in my personal life who care about me, and they are like, could you plz stop talking bout this already thank you very much  So yeah anyway this is an excellent reminder to be quiet and have a seat hahaha:D Thanks 